# How to combine List<T> with List<List<T>>?

Tags: c#, list

I have one `List<double>` and one `List<List<double>>`. Take example like :

```
List<double> Label = new List<double>{ 1, 0, 1 };
```

and

```
List<List<double>> Matrix = new List<List<double>>
{ 
   new List<double>{1.2, 1.5, 1.8},
   new List<double>{1.5, 1.8, 1.2},
   new List<double>{1.8, 1.2, 1.5}
};
```

I want to combine those lists and the output I want is like :

```
1  1.2  1.5  1.8
0  1.5  1.8  1.2
1  1.8  1.2  1.5
```

And for additional : the amount of data from the two lists is always same.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please check [this article about asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question by adding details/code.

Comment: I still newbie in this but I try like addRange, concat or some other but many examples I can find is only combine List with List not what I want so I get trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a simple `for` loop:

```
for (int r = 0; r < Matrix.Count; ++r) // for each row r in Matrix
  Matrix[r].Insert(0, Label[r]);       // we insert Label[r] item at 0th position
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree that the OP should at least post his/her attempt before asking this question, I can't resist trying it myself. Here's my attempt using Linq:

```
List<double> Label = new List<double> { 1, 0, 1 };
List<List<double>> Matrix = new List<List<double>>
{
   new List<double>{1.2, 1.5, 1.8},
   new List<double>{1.5, 1.8, 1.2},
   new List<double>{1.8, 1.2, 1.5}
};
var result = Label.Zip(Matrix, (l, m) => m.Prepend(l));
```

`result` has the type of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>`. This answer uses `Zip()` to combine two lists by prepending element from first list (`double`) to the element from second list (`List<double>`)

Comment: We all know that people will come here looking for a LINQ one-liner they can easily copy and paste into their production code without checking, so +1 :) By the way, `Zip` should work as well without explicit generic parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
@for(int i=0; i<Matrix.Count();i++) {
   var val = Label.get(i);   //get the corresponding value
   Matrix[i].Insert(0,val);  //insert val to beginning of this list entry
}
```